# how to insert data in wordpress table usnig jquery ajax

Tags: plugins, jquery, ajax

how to insert data in wordpress using jquery ajax for my plugin, i tried a lot but my action.php page not access global $wpdb, Please tell me where is the problem.

Here is the code of my submenu page of plugin

```
<?php
        function pincode()
        {
        ?>   

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function userAction(type,id){
            id = (typeof id == "undefined")?'':id;
            var statusArr = {add:"added",edit:"updated",delete:"deleted"};
            var userData = '';
            if (type == 'add') {
                userData = $("#addForm").find('.form').serialize()+'&action_type='+type+'&id='+id;
            }else if (type == 'edit'){
                userData = $("#editForm").find('.form').serialize()+'&action_type='+type;
            }else{
                userData = 'action_type='+type+'&id='+id;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                //url: 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/arunkumar/action.php',
                url : '<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'action.php';?>',
                data: userData,
                success:function(msg){
                    if(msg == 'ok'){
                        alert('User data has been '+statusArr[type]+' successfully.');
                        //getUsers();
                        $('.form')[0].reset();
                        $('.formData').slideUp();
                    }else{
                        //alert('Some problem occurred, please try again.');
                        $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+msg+' !</div>');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        </script>
                <div class="panel-heading">States <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="addLink" onclick="javascript:$('#addForm').slideToggle();"></a></div>
                <div class="panel-body none formData" id="addForm">
                    <h2 id="actionLabel">Add New State</h2>
                    <form class="form" id="userForm">
                        <div id="error"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>State Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter State Name" name="name" id="name"/>
                        </div>

                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="$('#addForm').slideUp();">Cancel</a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-success" onclick="userAction('add')">Add State</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
    <?php
    }
```

and this is action.php code where insert code is applied but it show " Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on null " error

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['action_type']) && !empty($_POST['action_type'])){
        if($_POST['action_type'] == 'add'){
            //echo $insert?'ok':'err';
            global $wpdb;
            $state_name = $_POST['name']; 
            $wpdb->insert( 'state',array( 'state_name' => $state_n),array('%s') );
            $status = $wpdb->insert_id;
            echo $status ? 'ok' : var_dump($wpdb);


        }
```

Comment: Where are you adding the second block of code? Directly to the page or as a wp_ajax action?

Comment: Hi @PedroCoitinho i'm adding second block of coding on another page name action.php in my plugin,but on action.php $wpdb not working

Answer (score 4):

The code you have shared can work in core PHP and not in Wordpress. Using AJAX in Wordpress plugin is explained in Wordpress documentation. Please refer - https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

I have tried this and it works well.

Comment: Nothing better than the codex reference. Should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

looks like Ravi Shinde is right:

> The code you have shared can work in core PHP and not in Wordpress.
>   Using AJAX in Wordpress plugin is explained in Wordpress
>   documentation. Please refer -
>   https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

To give your plugin access to the ajax interface you need to wrap it around WordPress' AJAX action `wp_ajax_{action}`

First, you need to define the action:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_user_action', 'user_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_user_action', 'user_action' );
```

Which registers the `user_action` with wordpress for both logged in and not authenticated users.

Then you build your handling function:

```
function user_action() {
    // since this gets loaded by wordpress
    // you get access to $wpdb and other
    // core functions
    global $wpdb; 

    $state_name = $_POST['name']; 

    $wpdb->insert( 'state',array( 'state_name' => $state_n),array('%s') );
    $status = $wpdb->insert_id;

    echo $status ? 'ok' : var_dump($wpdb);

    // Ajax calls in WP always need to be closed with wp_die:
    wp_die(); 
}
```

Finally, you need to get a reference the endpoint ( wordpress shares a single URL for all ajax calls ). In your JS:

```
var ajaxurl = <?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>;
```

Note: The "correct" way to register scripts is through `enqueue_scripts`, but thats beyond our scope right now.

Then you can do a regular Ajax call to `ajaxurl` and passing `{ action: 'user_action' }` as data.

Truth be told its not the best way, but you get used to it. If you need a primer, Smashinmag always has great articles:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

( Also: I haven't tested the code but is pretty standard and should work out of the box. Lemme know! )